# Using a UDF MySQL query from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, user-defined-functions

I read from the MySQL [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-udf.html)

> For the UDF mechanism to work, functions must be written in C or C++
>   and your operating system must support dynamic loading.
>
> ...
>
> A UDF contains code that becomes part of the running server, so when
>   you write a UDF, you are bound by any and all constraints that apply
>   to writing server code

I want to create a MySQL function on the fly (by submitting it with PHP's `mysqli`) so that I can use it in a subsequent query.

1. Will I be unable to create a function on a basic web-hosting server's installation of MySQL (e.g. HostGator, 1and1, GoDaddy) since I'm not the `root` admin user?
2. What is wrong with my syntax in the below query? It doesn't work either in the direct MySQL shell (the black box) or through my php script. The error returned is:

> Warning: mysqli::query() [mysqli.query]: (42000/1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter // create function IF NOT EXISTS LeaveNumber(str varchar(50)) retur' at line 1 in C:\wamp\www_quac\includes\database.php on line 55

This is my query in php:

```
if ($Database->query("
delimiter //

create function IF NOT EXISTS LeaveNumber(str varchar(50)) returns varchar(50)
no sql
begin
declare verification varchar(50);
declare result varchar(50) default '';
declare character varchar(2);
declare i integer default 1;

if char_length(str) > 0 then
    while(i <= char_length(str)) do
        set character = substring(str,i,1);
        set verification = find_in_set(character,'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0');

        if verification > 0 then
            set result = concat(result,character);
        end if;

        set i = i + 1;

    end while;

return result;
else
return '';
end if;
end //


delimiter ;")) { echo 'hey the function was written. its called LeaveNumber()'; }
```

Comment: side note...but: There should be a UDF tag.

Comment: side note: You should not tag [tag:mysql] questions with [tag:sql-server]. Please view [the tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info) and also see [this meta answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207274/suggested-tags-both-sql-server-and-mysql-are-suggested-by-the-system/219814#219814). Also the tag you wanted *does* exist, you just didn't look hard enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two syntax errors in your code:

- create function does not support `if exists`
- `character` is a reserved SQL keyword.

The below appears to work for me. I'd suggest using an SQL 'ide' such as MySQL workbench. It will show you syntax errors straight away.

```
DROP function  IF EXISTS LeaveNumber;

delimiter //

create function LeaveNumber(str varchar(50)) returns varchar(50)
no sql
begin
declare verification varchar(50);
declare result varchar(50) default '';
declare nextChar varchar(2);
declare i integer default 1;

if char_length(str) > 0 then
    while(i <= char_length(str)) do
        set nextChar = substring(str,i,1);
        set verification = find_in_set(nextChar,'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0');

        if verification > 0 then
            set result = concat(result,nextChar);
        end if;

        set i = i + 1;

    end while;

return result;
else
return '';
end if;
end //


delimiter ;
```

Comment: I actually found this out before you answered, but many thanks for the effort. Also, I never knew that about MySQL workbench. Very good to know